# ShapeRenderer LibGdx not working

Tags: java, libgdx

I don't know why the ShapeRenderer object is not drawing a circle on the screen. I tried modifying the code to include suggestions such as changing projection matrix and transform matrix of my shaperenderer object to the batch ones, and even adding batch.end() before shaperenderer.begin(). Here is my code:

```
public void draw (Batch batch, float parentAlpha){
    super.draw(batch, parentAlpha);
    batch.end();
    shapeRend.setProjectionMatrix(batch.getProjectionMatrix());
    shapeRend.setTransformMatrix(batch.getTransformMatrix());
    float x = body.getWorldCenter().x;
    float y = body.getWorldCenter().y;
    shapeRend.translate(x, y, 0);


    shapeRend.begin(ShapeType.Filled);
    shapeRend.setColor(Color.RED);
    shapeRend.circle(0, 0, Constants.PLAYER_RADIUS);
    shapeRend.end();
    batch.begin();


}
```

There is really no other code I could provide other than that Contants.player_radius = 0.2, which shouldn't make a difference. I have my world renderer (Box2D physics) which is visible but the shaperenderer circle is not there. Originally I did not put the translate function and just put the x and y directly into the shapeRend.circle (x, y, r) method call, but I was just testing different ways. Any suggestions would be helpful. Thank-you.

Comment: I believe if you do not set anything, the shaperenderer uses pixel coordinates. I recommend testing this first, and then adding transformations to it when you know this works.

Answer (score 2):

I am sorry for everyone who might have been confused by my question. I found out what was wrong. The thing is I am using a different orthographic camera which has a projection matrix which was a small square on the bottom left. I failed to change the projection matrix to the smaller left corner.

shapeRend.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

The batch's projection matrix wasn't configured to the camera's and that is why it failed.

I am not using shapeRenderer anymore anyway because I believe using textures are better. Thank-you for everyone who answered.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
public void create () {
    shapeRenderer = new ShapeRenderer();
    camera = new OrthographicCamera(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight()); 
}

@Override
public void render () {
     Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
     Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
     Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL20.GL_BLEND);
     Gdx.gl.glBlendFunc(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
     Gdx.gl.glDisable(GL20.GL_BLEND);

     shapeRenderer.setColor(Color.RED);
     shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeType.FilledCircle);
     shapeRenderer.filledCircle(25, 25, 25);
     shapeRenderer.end();
}
```

Comment: There is no static constant called FilledCircle in the ShapeType class and there is not filledCircle method in the ShapeRenderer class. I checked that also. I think they took it out. I added the first part of your suggestion to my code and it did not do the trick. I already had glClearColor and clClear, but not the blendfunction. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

**Kotlin**

You need to set the shapeRenderer.projectionMatrix in the resize function of libGDX. Otherwise the shapeRenderer won't work.

```
override fun render() {

    // camera

    camera?.update() //update our camera every frame

    // draw

    batch.begin()

    // background

    batch.draw(background, 0f, 0f, camera!!.viewportWidth, camera!!.viewportHeight)

    batch.end()

    // shapes

    shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Line)

    shapeRenderer.color = Color.BLUE
    shapeRenderer.circle(myCircle.x, myCircle.y, myCircle.radius)

    shapeRenderer.end()

}

override fun resize(width: Int, height: Int) {

    // aspect fill

    viewport!!.update(width, height, true)

    batch.projectionMatrix = camera!!.combined

    shapeRenderer.projectionMatrix = camera!!.combined;

}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 

Comment: Whatever language this is, it's not Java, as tagged in the question, and there is no explanation for writing in a different language. Please remove it or add an explanation.